# Is there a svn client for Visual studio online?

Tags: svn, azure-devops, svn-client

I'm trying to add resources to our Visual studio online SVN, but without using Visual studio or any visual studio plugin.

Does someone know if this is possible? I tried with only tortoise SVN, but no luck. It shows that it move to an endless long url, that i can't copy. And the combination of Tortoise SVN en SVN Bridge doesn't help either.

Also it's kind hard to find any information about it on google as Visual Studio Online, will find all visual studio resources.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) doesn't support Subversion for source control. It only supports Git and Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC).

EDIT: You can use VSTS as a build system for code stored in an external SVN repository. The [Visual Studio docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/repository#subversion) will show you how.
Be aware that this doesn't mean you can use VSTS to actually host your Subversion repository.

Comment: O... That's interesting, i swear that it's named svn in most places..
But ok. Do you know ay good client (program) for TFVC in that case?

Comment: The git-tf and git-tfs tools both add map a local git repository to a server hosted TFVC repository and may work for you. Alternatively use the tf command line tool. It's added when you install  Team Explorer (windows) or the Team Explorer Everywhere command line client (non-windows)